# On Windows, who is in the Everyone and Authenticated Users groups?

Tags: windows, security, named-pipes, access-control

My application uses a Named Pipe to do IPC. What access control should I place on it, to provide broad local only access?

The pipe is created by the .net 2.0 remoting protocol, and it already has an ACL for the 'NETWORK' group to deny all access, so I think only local users can access it. In my remoting configuration file I need to pick an 'authorizedGroup' who can access this pipe.

I would like any process running on the local machine to access my named pipe.

I would appear to need to select between access for the 'Everyone' Group or the 'Authenticated Users' group. Given the local-only access, what processes might be running under the 'Everyone' group that are not in the 'Authenticated Users' group?

I'm interested in answers for Windows XP and above.

Answer (score 2):

"Everyone" is a collective group for "Authenticated Users" and "Guest". Note that for Win 2000 and earlier, it included "Anonymous" too where no checks are made

"Authenticated Users" is user who has logged into AD and has a login token.

My text is paraphrasing of Windows Server 2003 "[Security identifiers](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc780850(WS.10).aspx)".

Edit, "Network" from the link:

> Includes all users who are logged on
>   through a network connection. Access
>   tokens for interactive users do not
>   contain the Network SID.

To be honest, I've never thought about this one much... sorry.

Comment: Two questions:
 - Are 'Anonymous' users from the network, by definition?
 - Is the guest account used by the Windows 'Guest access' feature users can turn on/off in the users control panel?

Comment: Incidentally, I dont think 'Authenticated Users' has to be anything to do with AD. I believe, for example, the LocalSystem account is in Authenticated Users, and the group also works on standalone machines.

Comment: True, I always think in network terms. However, each workgroup is effectively it's own domain if you think about it.

Comment: Does that include Service Accounts? Does it include computer accounts? Does it included users in trusted domains?

Comment: @NickWhaley "Everyone" does include computer accounts. (See http://serverfault.com/questions/569232/are-windows-computer-accounts-eg-domain-machine1-included-in-the-everything.)