# XAMPP on Windows 8.1 - Can't edit files in htdocs

Tags: xampp

I'm using XAMPP on Windows 8.1. When I'm trying to edit files located in htdocs folder, it does not allow me to save the changes.

Alert message looks like:

> Unable to save:
>       Error: Access is denied

Comment: I can't give you exact solution but i remember that i had similar problem on Windows 7. I had to enable administrator permission to xampp folder and i also disabled UAC. However it might be that you can't edit/save file if file is used by another program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Right click on the `htdocs` folder and then select `Properties`
2. Move to the `Security` tab
3. Select `Advanced` and then `Owner`
4. Change the owner to `Administrator`
5. On the `Permissions` window click on the `Add` button to open the `Group or user names`- you can enter `everyone` and then click `OK`
6. Select `Full Control` by placing a check mark on `Allow`

Check also:

1. [Add group "Everyone" to directory and all of it's sub-directories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4464467/add-group-everyone-to-directory-and-all-of-its-sub-directories)
2. [On Windows, who is in the Everyone and Authenticated Users groups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1040353/on-windows-who-is-in-the-everyone-and-authenticated-users-groups)
3. [How to use batch file to give a folder permission to the Everyone group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23526361/how-to-use-batch-file-to-give-a-folder-permission-to-the-everyone-group)
4. [How to create directory with all rights granted to everyone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/690780/how-to-create-directory-with-all-rights-granted-to-everyone)